# How to wrap HTML substring in tags?

Tags: javascript, html, replace, word-wrap

I need to wrap a part of a HTML string in a new element with Javascript. For example from this:

```
<div>This is some text.<b title="some text">This is some other element</b></div>
```

To this:

```
<div>This is <a>some text</a>.<b title="some text">This is some other element</b></div>
```

This is my current code, simplified:

```js
var s = "some text"
var regExp = RegExp(s, 'i');
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(regExp, '<a>$&</a>');
```

```html
<div>This is some text.<b title="some text">This is some other element</b></div>
```

This code works in trivial cases, but fails when there are child elements with markup matching my search filter, as in the title attribute above. Also it seems to break element references as the elements are re-initialized when innerHTML is set (and innerHTML seems to be very much discouraged).

I think this should be doable by finding a textNode, parsing it, and create new nodes in its place, but I struggle getting it to work.

Comment: Just create a temporary element, and add the string as HTML. Then use DOM parsers to extract/modify the elements.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not a regular language thus it can't be (completely) parsed by regex. See this post about it: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your text in a span you can use this code:

```
<div id="id1"><span>This is some text.</span><b title="some text">This is some other element</b><span class="some text">some text</span></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var id = document.getElementById("id1");

    var all = id.querySelectorAll("*");
    var length = all.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        all[i].innerHTML = all[i].innerHTML.replace('some text', '<a>some text</a>');      
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering I finally got it to work, only by modifying the DOM directly.

```
// JQuery required for this line.
var textNodes = $.grep(element.childNodes, function(n) { return n.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE });

// Assume there is only one text node in element (I know this from my use case).
if (textNodes.length > 0) {
  var textNode = textNodes[0];
  var regExp = RegExp('^(.*)('+someText+')(.*)', 'i');
  var matches = textNode.nodeValue.match(regExp);
  textNode.nodeValue = matches[1];
  var matchNode = document.createElement('U');
  matchNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(matches[2]));
  label.insertBefore(matchNode, textNode.nextSibling);
  suffixNode = document.createTextNode(matches[3]);
  label.insertBefore(suffixNode, matchNode.nextSibling);
}
```

Introducing a new span element and set the innerHTML of that would have worked too, but I prefer keeping the DOM as clean as possible.